# Как выглядит трехмерный массив в C#?

Tags: c#

Как можно представить трехмерный массив. Можете картинку прикрепить.

```
using System;

class ThreeDMatrix
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[,,] m = new int[3, 3, 3];
        int sum = 0;
        int n = 1;

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                    m[x, y, z] = n++;

        sum = m[0, 0, 0] + m[1, 1, 1] + m[2, 2, 2];

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of first diagonal: " + sum);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше не представлять, это вредно, потом понадобится 5ти мерный, но на самом деле он выглядит как ряд чисел (одномерный массив) просто для него есть описание

Comment: а какое представление интересует, в памяти или, так сказать, в объеме?

Comment: Чтобы реально посмотреть "Как выглядит трехмерный массив?" нужно просто набрать этот вопрос в поисковике и в списке фильтров выбрать "**Картинки**"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Вы [**кубик Рубика**](http://www.kom-kov.ru/files/Image/00073.jpeg) видели когда-нибудь? Так вот Ваш трехмерный массив с размерами 3x3x3 и выглядит как тот самый кубик Рубика.

Comment: отлично! (6 символов нужно.)

Answer (score 2):

3-x мерный массив в коде (C#)

```
int[,,] array = { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } } };
```

Его перебор:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < array.GetLength(2); k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[i, j, k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Представь параллелепипед, разделенный на равные ячейки. Тогда каждая ячейка будет представлять собой элемент, у которого имеется 3 координаты - x,y,z.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проассоцировать с осями в трехмерном пространстве. Измерения массива будут расположены так же.

Answer (score 0):

Представь, что твой массив это кубик XYZ , главной гранью , пусть будет X- высота,
остальные грани соединяются с X - Y,Z.
ПУСТЬ X ИМЕЕТ ВЫСОТУ равную 2 блокам памяти в каждом из которых хранится 1 число,
пусть 1 и 3 , Y = 2 блокам памяти, 4 и 5 (числа)
              Z = 2 блокам памяти, 7 и 8 (числа)
Тогда первому блоку памяти X соответствует первые блоки памяти Y, Z
Тогда все будет выглядеть вот так XY [1,4]
                                  XZ [1,7]